# Azure monitoring agent vs Log Analytics Agent

Tags: azure-monitoring

What is the difference between Azure monitoring agent and Log Analytics Agent.
How can we verify if these are installed?

I see two options :

1. Check the extensions page of the VM on portal.
2. Verify the installed programs to find the agent.

Are these mutually exclusive?

If my goal is to have enabled Log analytics then I only need Log Analytics Agent, is this true?

This is taken from [log analytics agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agent-windows#verify-agent-connectivity-to-azure-monitor). Why is it called 'monitoring agent' ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitoring Agent(in preview now) replaces log analytics. Since you are starting with installation and if the OS is [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agents-overview#supported-operating-systems) then use Azure Monitoring agent.
The log analytics agent installation with .exe is only for on premise VMs. For Azure VMs The log analytics agent can be installed with a click(attach) in log anlaytics workspace.

Azure Monitoring Agent can be installed easily with powershell as an extension and then the [DCR (data collection rules)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collection-rule-azure-monitor-agent) can be set.

Overview of all agents are given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agents-overview).